# Modal effect for multi-level windows in WPF

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog

Salutations,

I have been unable to find a way to apply a "fading" or "darkening" to my application when a modal window appears. I have multiple windows, so lets say the application as window1, can launch window2, which can launch a modal window3. When I try to apply any effects, I can only seem to be able to darken (or blur or whatever else I feel like) the immediate parent (window2), or the entire monitor space (which I do not want).

How can I apply an effect to all windows of the application, leaving only the current active/modal one clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an object (boolean?) to the resources of the App object and bind an overlay that you put in each window.

Bind the Visibility and IsEnabled properties of the Window to prevent the user tabbing to the controls underneath the overlay.

When you open or close a Modal dialog, toggle the object.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
            <sys:Boolean x:Key="IsShowingModalDialog">false</sys:Boolean>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Definitely something I would not have thought to do. Due to the sheer number of windows though, we have decided to hold off on modal effects for now. But your answer is certainly on the list of possible solutions for later.

Comment: Personally, I dislike having more than one window. In an application with more than one View (UserControl) I added a little bit of code to my base class for the Views that registers for a Message (MVVMLight Messenger) (ShowingModalDialogMessage) that is send by the Window when it displays a modal dialog and changes the VisualState of the UserControl.